# Swiftmailer message headers appearing in message and not being processed

Tags: swiftmailer

This script is designed to attach a PDF to a HTML email. The email itself sends fine, and I can see that the attachment is sending too, however my problem is that the email headers do not seem to be getting processed, and so I can see the headers in the email body itself and my attachment shows in the email body as a base64 encoded string.

```
    $attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance(file_get_contents($this->pdf), ucfirst($type) . '-VIP-membership-welcome-pack.pdf', 'application/pdf');

    $this->message
            ->setSubject($this->subject)
            ->setBody($this->body, 'text/html')
            ->setTo([$orderDetails['EmailAddress']])
            ->setBcc(['support@harpoonmedia.co.uk', $this->defaultHeaders['to']])
            ->setFrom([$this->defaultHeaders['from']]);

    $this->message->attach($attachment);
```

I've tried adding the file using Swift_Mailers `::fromPath` method, and got the same response - when there is no attachment I see the HTML is added to the email correctly.

Here is an example of the output (truncated)

```
--_=_swift_v4_1417539844_a449b32848d1edc3be2f0d67f968c81675770047_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type=3D"text/css">
 #hkemail #outlook a{padding:0;}
 #hkemail body{width:100% !important;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-    adjust:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
 #hkemail .ExternalClass{width:100%;}=20
 #hkemail .ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass span,.E=
xternalClass font,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div{line-height:100%;}
 #hkemail .bodytbl{margin:0;padding:0;width:100% !important;}=20
 #hkemail img{outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolatio=
 n-mode:bicubic;display:block;}=20
 #hkemail a img{border:none;}
```

That's a piece of the HTML body that is output in the message, and heres some of the attachment that is output in the message body:

```
 --_=_swift_v4_1417539844_a449b32848d1edc3be2f0d67f968c81675770047_=_
 Content-Type: application/pdf; name=Gold-VIP-membership-welcome-pack.pdf
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Gold-VIP-membership-welcome-pack.pdf

 JVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjQgMCBvYmoNPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZCAxL0wgMTE3ODY4MC9PIDYvRSAx
 MTE5NzczL04gMS9UIDExNzg0ODEvSCBbIDEzOTYgMjY0XT4+DWVuZG9iag0gICAgICAgICAgICAg
 DQp4cmVmDQo0IDU1DQowMDAwMDAwMDE2IDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDE2NjAgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAw
 MDAwMTcyMCAwMDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMDAxOTk0IDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDI0MjcgMDAwMDAgbg0K
 MDAwMDAwMjU4NCAwMDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMDAyNjE4IDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDU2OTggMDAwMDAg
```

and obviously this carries on for ages.

Any help much appreciated thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Did you manage to find out what's causing it? Do you have a fix you could post please? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't, it was an absolute nightmare and i'm confident that I followed the documentation to the letter - in the end I went with a different php mailer library, sorry!

Comment: I think I went with PHPMailer in the end

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply. This is driving me nuts. Could it be because I'm sending from MAMP localhost? I'll try it up on a proper server perhaps.

Comment: it wasn't in my case, as I tested on the staging server as well as my local environment, I hope it works for you though!

Comment: Figured it out, see below!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and realised I was using a DEV version - Swift-5.3.1-DEV (therefore possibly unstable).

After downgrading to the latest stable version Swift-5.3.0, I can now see this issue gone.

I did not use Composer to install the latest stable, but instead found myself using the ZIP from SwiftMailer's GitHub account. This version is the DEV version, so make sure you're getting the latest stable release: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/releases

Hope this helps.

Comment: nice - I didn't think to try and change the library version, I'll set this up again this evening and give it a try and let you know if that resolves the problem for me too.

Comment: 5.4.1 - stable affects this bug too